# Selecting a partial string name before some characters in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, slice

I have quite a few column names with below format:

```
A-1_45_GG___________________LL
B_2_45_GLKK___________________KK
```

I am looking for a generic approach to select string name before the long underscore characters. So my desired output will be columns renamed as `[A-1_45_GG, B_2_45_GL]`. How do I accomplish that in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more approach would be to split the string via regex.

```
import re

lst = ["A-1_45_GG___________________LL", "B_2_45_GLKK___________________KK"]

print([re.split("[_]{2,}", i)[0] for i in lst])
```

Output:

```
['A-1_45_GG', 'B_2_45_GLKK']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Well if you never have a double underscore in your name you could yust split it by "__" and then take the first index**

```
string = "A-1_45_GG___________________LL"
string.split("__")[0]
```

**Output:**

```
'A-1_45_GG'
```

**If you were to use a list:**

```
yourlist = ["A-1_45_GG___________________LL", "B_2_45_GLKK___________________KK"]

print(list(map(lambda x: x.split("__")[0], yourlist)))
```

**Output:**

```
['A-1_45_GG', 'B_2_45_GLKK']
```